# Training of nu-SVR taking too much time

Tags: python, scikit-learn

i'm running a nu-SVR model on a a large data set, i'm using sklearn, but the training is taking too much time and i don't even use grid search for best parameters, i fixed the C and nu parameters.

```
 clf = NuSVR(kernel="rbf",C=15.0, nu=0.3)
```

is there anyway to speed up training ?

Comment: SVMs scale badly with many samples and non-linear kernels somewhat forbid alternatives (like SGDRegressor which can be used on huge data for a linear SVM). So no. Nothing you can do in general (although some values of C,nu might be trained faster; depends on your data if those are good or not). Drop kernels or look for another regressor.

Comment: Also first try standardizing your data which may help svms run a little faster.

Comment: thanks for your answers, yes my data are standardized @VivekKumar.

Comment: @sascha the SVM regressor gives me the best result, for the configuration i gave you above ( C=15.0, nu=0.3 ) it took 3 hours to finish training, is there anything that i could do, i have a i7 intel with 8g of RAM it's not a hardware problem

Comment: I already said: it's an algorithmic problem (and you already use the de-facto standard lib to optimize this).

Answer (score 0):

If possible use polynomial kernel instead of rbf and set the `max_iter` field while initializing the nuSVR.

```
clf = NuSVR(kernel="poly",C=15.0, nu=0.3, max_iter=10000)
```

This decreased the time in my case but it may or may not converge.